# jQuery live update buttons text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to live update the "Button text value" with the "Textbox value" and cant seem to figure out the issue with this code, what am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$(window).load(function(){

  $('#TextBox').keypress(function(e){
    var val=this.value;
    $('#Button').val(val);
  });

});//]]> 

</script>

<body>

<input id="TextBox" type="text" value="" />
<br /><br />
<input id="Button" type="button" value="Button" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method is deprecated in jQuery version `1.8`  and removed in `3.0` so instead use [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) .

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#TextBox').keypress(function(e) {
      var val = this.value;
      $('#Button').val(val);
    });

  }); //]]>
</script>

<input id="TextBox" type="text" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="Button" type="button" value="Button" />
```

---

**FYI :** Although you can use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) or [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event instead of `keypress` event which would be much better.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#TextBox').keyup(function(e) {
      var val = this.value;
      $('#Button').val(val);
    });

  }); //]]>
</script>

<input id="TextBox" type="text" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="Button" type="button" value="Button" />
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#TextBox').on('input', function(e) {
      var val = this.value;
      $('#Button').val(val);
    });

  }); //]]>
</script>

<input id="TextBox" type="text" value="" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="Button" type="button" value="Button" />
```

Comment: first time it gets null value